# Oracle SQL - REGEXP_LIKE contains characters other than string 'NA'

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-like

I would like to create a query where I select all records which contain characters that are `a-z` or `A-Z`,not allowed string `'NA'`

```
select *
  from tz_customers c 
 where REGEXP_LIKE(c.customercode,'^NA');
```

`REGEXP_LIKE` allow all characters other STRING `'NA'`

Answer (score 2):

I might use an inequality comparison to exclude `NA`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tz_customers
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(customercode, '^[A-Za-z]+$') AND
    customercode <> 'NA';
```

In principle we *could* try to use a negative lookahead in a single regex pattern to exclude `NA`, but I'm not sure if Oracle regex supports that.

Comment: Depending on what the OP really means, the second condition might be `LIKE '%NA%'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want strings that do not start witn `NA` then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tz_customers c
WHERE  c.customercode NOT LIKE 'NA%'
```

If you want strings that don't contain `NA` anywhere then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tz_customers c
WHERE  c.customercode NOT LIKE '%NA%'
```

If you want strings that aren't exactly `NA` then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tz_customers c
WHERE  c.customercode <> 'NA'
```

If you want strings that only have alphabet characters then you can use `TRANSLATE` to strip the allowed characters and test whether the remaining string is empty (`NULL`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tz_customers c
WHERE  TRANSLATE(
         c.customercode,
         '1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
         '1'
       ) IS NULL
```

If you want to combine the two then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tz_customers c
WHERE  TRANSLATE(
         c.customercode,
         '1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
         '1'
       ) IS NULL
AND    c.customercode <> 'NA'
```

So for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tz_customers ( customercode ) AS
  SELECT 'NA'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BANANA'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BANANA2' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> | CUSTOMERCODE |
> | :----------- |
> | BANANA       |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4b1c228aca5bdb02c284b4635c3cf501)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need regexp_like:

```
  select * from tz_customers where customer_code not like '%NA%'
```